# PlatformFile selectedFile Type: PlatformFile The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i was following along a curse on youtube, but he made a list like this 'List selectedFiles = List();' and it gave me an error so i did it like this 'List selectedFiles = [];'
but now it gives me an error and idk if it is because of that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h5Rx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5zWN.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use null check operator on `selectedFile.path` as it could be null at run time.

Comment: can u show an example?

Comment: You can either first check if the path is not null or you can use an exclamation mark like selected file!.path or selectedFile.path!

Comment: Also if you hover onto the error text the ide might show you some quick fixes

Comment: thank you so much, yea i did the quick fixes thing but it didn't help.

Comment: Same problem or new one ... Add it in the problem description

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `selectedFile` null variable to a non-null form of it.

You do that by adding the exclamation mark(!) as a post fix to the null variable.

**Solution:**

Change this:

```dart
File file = File(selectedFile.path)
```

to this;

```dart
File file = File(selectedFile!.path)
```

**Note:**

This could fail at runtime if selectedFile is actually null.

You can mitigate this issue by checking if the value is null like this:

```dart
if (selectedFile != null) { 
  File file = File(selectedFile!.path)
  //Other operations
} else {
  print('selectedFile is null');
}
```